# Is it possible to use a Gibbs sampler for uncertainty propagation?

Tags: bayesian, uncertainty, gibbs, quantile-regression

Situation:
10 basic numeric properties are predicted using quantile regression forest, then they are put into a desicion rule system to decide land management. The desicion rules result in one class (out of 20 possible classes) derived from these 10 properties.

I would like to propagate the uncertainty from the predictive distribution of the quantile regression forest (= non-parametric bootstrap uncertainty) into the end product of these management classes. The aim is to have a result like e.g. "for a certain prediction location the managment class remained the same in 80 % of the cases" given the uncertainty in my basic property prediction.

The 10 basic properties are not independent. **Can I use a Gibbs sampler to sample from the predictive distributions created by quantile regression forest?**

As I do not know the joint distribution of the 10 properties, the Gibbs sampler would allow to approximate the joint distribution by its conditional sampling approach.

Or, what would be wrong with that? I was not able to find an application following such an approach, hence I assume, I must be wrong somewhere?